# Viewport argument key "shrink-to-fit" not recognized and ignored. in Safari Browser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, safari

[image: This is the page when i using chrome.]I have a project in Asp.net MVC (C#). And When I run using Safari

```
Viewport argument key "shrink-to-fit" not recognized and ignored.
```

Error Coming in Safari Browser. Both Chrome and Mozilla having no such error found. I lost the design (css) in Safari Browser too.

[image: This is the image when i using Safari]

```
 Image 1 -  When using Chrome
 Image 2-  When Using Safari
```

Comment: Related: [What does the shrink-to-fit viewport meta attribute do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33767533/what-does-the-shrink-to-fit-viewport-meta-attribute-do). What Safari version used to render your view page?

Comment: Safari Version 5.1.7