# Which meta viewport tag should I set if web page doesn't have a mobile version?

Tags: html, mobile, browser

I'm working on a web page that has no mobile version. I want portable devices to show full, zoomed out version firstly. After reading few manuals I concluded that correct viewport meta tag should look like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1200px">
```

Because I need a virtual viewport of width 1200px to show my webpage properly. However github(it has mobile version but it's possible to load desktop one on phones) and Youtrack has meta viewport tag like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
```

Both options lead to the same result. How do you think, which solution fits web standards better?

Comment: See [33767533](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33767533/what-does-the-shrink-to-fit-viewport-meta-attribute-do). I think `width=1200px` is similar to `width=device-width`, while `shrink-to-fit=no` overrides a related behaviour.

Comment: I see, it's copied from CRA. I'm changing the question a bit.